# MySql LIKE in reverse?

Tags: mysql

I have a column named 'titles' with the values:

1) Harry Potter

2) Harry

3) Harry Po

4) Mario Potter

5) Hanry Plotter

If i make a search like:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE titles LIKE 'Harry Potter%'
```

i get only the first row with 'Harry Potter' which is ok.
But how can i get the 2nd and the 3rd row also as a result because they match the search string 'Harry Potter' (Harry Potter contains Harry, Harry Potter contains Harry Po). BUT not "Harry Potter" Not contains "Mario Potter"

I am looking for a function like: if search_string contains ROW

Thanks

Comment: You have to define the rule a bit better.. Should Potter, Harry be returned? Or Harry, the boy who lived, Potter?

Comment: If i search for "Harry Potter" all the rows which are a part of and beginning  "Harry Potter"  should returned like "Ha", "Harry", "Harry Po". BUT NOT "Potter".  I am editing  the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIKE` with your column surrounded by wildcards:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE 'Harry Potter' LIKE CONCAT('%', titles, '%')
```

If you have a long term need for such searches, you might want to look into using MySQL's [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities.

Comment: Thanks! its working